# Finding duplicates using SQL

Tags: sql, duplicates

I am trying to write a query that will display all duplicates in a table.

I have a table, lets call it WORKERS.  This table has multiple columns; the two I am focusing on are called SocialSecurityNbr and EmpNbr.

I would like the query to display all rows where

```
SocialSecNbr == SocialSecNbr 
AND 
EmpNbr != EmpNbr
```

Below I have an example of my data followed by what I want the output to show.  (for the simplicity of this question I have only used 4 digits to represent the social security number)

```
ID  EmpNbr  SocialSecNbr EmpName
1   00001   9711         Smith,John
2   00002   5789         Harris, Greg
3   00001   9711         Smith,John
4   00003   4100         Thompson,Lisa
5   00004   1250         Fulton,Kyle
6   00005   3999         Harris, Amber
7   00004   1250         Fulton,Kyle
8   00007   1250         Morlan,Richard
9   00008   3999         Levy,Harold
```

What I would like to see as the output:

```
ID  EmpNbr  SocialSecurityNbr EmpName
5   00004   1250              Fulton,Kyle
6   00005   3999              Harris, Amber
7   00004   1250              Fulton,Kyle
8   00007   1250              Morlan,Richard
9   00008   3999              Levy,Harold
```

As you can see above all of the duplicate Social Security numbers are shown in the output, except for John Smith.  In the actual table there are many instances where the same person is shown more than once, this is fine and I do not what to see this in the outcome.

I have searched online for information on how to do this but all I found was examples using "Count > 1".  I'm thinking I need to use "Distinct" however I do not believe that I can apply that function to just one column.

Comment: If you use "DISTINCT" then it will return only distinct (different) values not the same value so you have to be aware during using "DISTINCT".

Comment: @sentilkumar, "Duplicate" here means "same SSN for different DB entities"

Comment: @STLDeveloper, I'm using Microsoft Access.

Comment: Are you querying a SQL Server database engine? If so, there are some interesting options.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, no I don't believe so.  The table WORKERS was created from an excel file I imported into Access; so the database is local to my computer.

Comment: No worries. The Access database engine can't execute some of the newer SQL statement options that are available in SQL Server. Any of the queries below should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

At least for ms-sql joining table with itself will work:

```
select distinct w1.ID, w1.EmpNbr, w1.SocialSecNbr, w1.EmpName
from WORKERS w1
inner join WORKERS s2 on w1.SocialSecNbr = s2.SocialSecNbr  
                         AND 
                         w1.EmpNbr  <> s2.EmpNbr
```

for other sql flavours it should work as well.

See sample at [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4e554/10/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using an `exists` clause:

```
select ID, EmpNbr, SocialSecurityNbr, EmpName
from workers w
where exists (select 1
              from workers w2
              where w2.SocialSecurityNbr = w.SocialSecurityNbr and
                    w2.EmpNbr <> w.EmpNbr
             );
```

With an index on `workers(SocialSecurityNbr, EmpNbr)`, this should be relatively efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The query below will show you all rows in Workers where the SocSecurityNbr has "duplicates" (as defined by having multiple different EmpNames).

```
SELECT *
FROM Workers
WHERE SocSecurityNbr IN (
    SELECT SocSecurityNbr
    FROM Workers
    GROUP BY SocSecurityNbr
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT EmpName) > 1
)
```

You could easily modify this to change your definition of a "duplicate" - for example, if there are multiple different employee numbers.